# Show only specific files in the folder view of Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

In a folder of hundreds of image files, I want to see only **specific files** (e.g. fileA.jpg, file783_asdf.jpg, file888sjs.jpg...). Note that I'm not talking about wildcards search, as files don't follow any naming patterns (and can be 30, 40 in number.)

So that out of all the files in that folder, only those desired ones are displayed in view — and then  enables me to sort those via various columns (size, name, date, medium icons, large icons, etc.) *just like a normal folder view*.

Is that possible to do natively in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many files you have, you could use Windows Search with boolean operators. It isn't concise, but it's the only way I can think of to do so natively within Explorer.

Going on your example, I would craft the query like this:
`name:"fileA.jpg" OR name:"file783_asdf.jpg" OR name:"file888sjs.jpg"`

I believe the Windows Search Bar has a 260 character limit, which might well...*limit*... your success. You can also try it without the `name` qualifier, but with personal tests, it didn't work without it, because I had similarly named files that came up.

Comment: I've been doing exactly that but unfortunately the number of files (and their lengthy names) make this method unreliable and it obviously breaks with the limits too.

Comment: I'm nevertheless upvoting this as it's partially useful for limited purposes, and will wait for any workaround to fully solve my problem. (Do you know of any easy non-native way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?). Thank you very much.

Comment: You can squeeze more filenames into your search using the syntax: `name:("name1.txt" OR "name2.txt" OR ...)`

Comment: @KeithMiller Your suggestion indeed works for longer queries! I just tried it with 19 long filenames (total length of query 4154 chars). So what are the limits here? Thanks!

Comment: @spcsLrg I don't know offhand. I hadn't done any testing. I was only thinking of the characters saved by not re-typing "`name:`" each time.  Are you constructing your query string using code?

Comment: @KeithMiller I have small lists of files (30/40 in no) which I need to see from the large folder. One of the list I took to quickly construct a query using a spreadsheet. It worked on that list (as above), but on a larger set it fails, so there is some limit at play here (not sure whether it's the number of files or query length). Can you point to a resource which might mention it? If I know the limits I can at least work within it reliably for now. Thanks again.

Comment: I have now turned the above comment to @KeithMiller into a question here https://superuser.com/q/1595063/1009802 . Thanks all.